# Como fazer ao clicar num button aparecer um form com js?

Tags: javascript, html

Procurei, pelo stackoverflow e não encontrei nada semelhante, então aqui vai a pergunta:

Como posso fazer, que ao clicarem em 1 button, aparecer automáticamente 1 form na mesma página com js?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn_form');
var form = document.getElementById('my_form');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  form.style.display = 'block';
});
```

```css
#my_form {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn_form">Mostrar Form</button>

<form id="my_form">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Para fazeres toggle (esconder/mostrar) carregando no mesmo botão:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn_form');
var form = document.getElementById('my_form');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if(form.style.display != 'block') {
    form.style.display = 'block';
    return;
  }
  form.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
#my_form {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn_form">Mostrar Form</button>

<form id="my_form">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
#form {
   display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<button id="button">Clique aqui</button>
<form id="form">
    <!--Seu form aqui -->
</form>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", displayForm);
function displayForm() {
    document.getElementById("form").style.display = 'block';
}
```

Te recomendo usar jQuery pra esses eventos de click e fadeIn, mas como vc nao especificou, usei o JS vanila